# Disabling android services in init.rc

Tags: android, android-service, android-source, android-build

I am working on a new hardware platform on which i need to flash Android OS..
For initial testing i need to stop all the Android services are there in android init.rc file.
I searched for the init.rc file in my code base
`./bootable/diskinstaller/init.rc
./bootable/recovery/etc/init.rc 
./system/core/rootdir/init.rc`
, I need to know about how to identify the android services in the init.rc ?.I am thinking of disabling the android dalvik VM. to stop all the android related services is it good to stop the dalvic VM or just disabling all the services one by one? Thanks!

Comment: The service you mean is ActivityManagerService, PackageManagerService, PowerManagerService?

Comment: yeah...all the android services...that gets initialized during the android boot-up

Comment: may i know,have you got any solution

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have sucessfully booted, then you can shutdown the android framework with this command:

```
setprop vold.decrypt trigger_shutdown_framework
```

This command was implemented as part of the encryption system in Honeycomb. It will shutdown all but the core native sevices:

- init
- adbd - so that you can still adb shell into the phone
- servicemanager  - Which handles the native (not android) serivces
- ueventd

You can restart the android framework with the command:

```
setprop vold.decrypt trigger_restart_framework
```

Obviously you must be root to do this.

Comment: yes, later on read about this property , but the actual scenario is different.need to stop the the framework from loading...

Comment: `trigger_restart_framework` appears to also stop adbd on Android 10 :/

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot, and came to a particular solution to disable the Android services which might work, there is a init.rc file in Android source code

```
./system/core/rootdir/init.rc
```

this init.rc file describes the system services, file system and other parameters that need to be set up.
As **init process** is the first process which get executed after the kernel loaded,the init process looks for this **init.rc** script file and then parsed it and launch the system service processes.
  There is a service called **Zygote (dalvic VM)** used to initialise the **SystemServer.java**,the first java component to run in the system,which contains declarations for all the Android services.

`service zygote /system/bin/app_process -Xzygote /system/bin --zygote --start-system-server
    class main`
  `socket zygote stream 660 root system`
   `onrestart write /sys/android_power/request_state wake`
    `onrestart write /sys/power/state on`
    `onrestart restart media`
    `onrestart restart netd`

the android services are declared in **run()** method of **SystemServer.java**.The path for the file is 
`/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java`
If we comment out the zygote,the android services might not initialized.I haven't tested it due to some panic in kernel booting but hope it will be the solution.:)

Comment: No, zygote is one of the key service, all system service in systemserver and all application processes are started by zygote. If you stop that, your system won't boot.

Comment: i came across this issue,that the android system wont boot,but eventually the init.rc initiates all the basic native services and zygote is one of them.and the zygote is the one which creates a socket  and responsible for handling all the android services...it just a try to stop all the services...

Comment: Generally, you cannot do anything if you stop all these services. And zygote is responsible to fork all Android application processes.

Comment: Thanks..Basically i just want to see the kernel loading properly without the android system and whether its showing some kernel logs..once it will done then it will be easier to debug all the services on the new hardware board!!